# How to set product tier price from Magento root using a script?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to set product tier price using script. I tried it many ways like:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($_product->getId()),array('tier_price' => $tierPrices),$product->getStoreId());
```

and

```
$_product->getResource()->saveAttribute($tierPrices, 'tier_price');
```

But I failed.

Comment: What do you mean by "you failed"? Readers will probably need more information than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this script.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<YOUR PRODUCT ID>);

$tierPrices[] = array(
            'cust_group'    => '1',
            'price_qty' => '2',
            'price'   => '95',
            'website_id' => '0'
         );

$product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);

$product->save();
```

Comment: Hi Manoj ,  This Script Gives Error Check This Screen Shot : http://prntscr.com/fanfwn

Comment: Hello Sanjay, Are you creating new product or updating the existing one?

Comment: Hello Manoj,  I am Updating Existing Product.

Comment: Can you please provide me the screenshot of script and the product that screenshot which you are updating.?

Comment: Hi Manoj , I am Get $tierPrice and $qty From My Csv And Here is my Piece Of Code . http://prntscr.com/fapedh